# Recognize user who has signed up with Google but tries to sign in with email in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I'm using AWS Cognito Federated Identities to enable social login with Google in a web app.

Attempts:

1. User (with email foo@gmail.com) signin/signup by Google
2. User login by email foo@gmail.com

Normal behavior: In the 2nd attempt, user will get an error *UserNotFoundException*

Expected response: my web will inform user, that he should login by google